# How to get mouse captured element

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I need to get mouse captured element to ReleaseMouseCapture for it.
I have a problem with cancelling MouseLeftButtonUp event when element is already pressed.
I need to cancel it before execution MouseLeftButtonUp.

Comment: What you are asking isn't possible, can you eloborate the scenario, you will need a sideways option?

Comment: When I have panel with some content I need to process mouseup event firstly on my panel and then on content.
I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried putting a transparent panel on top of everything and catch events there?  You will have to do some calculations to figure out what button they were trying to click on as the event won't have that, but it would allow you first access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a mechanism to intercept the event before it executes on the source element.  This is not possible in Silverlight, the source element has first dibs on the event.